# Multiplicative order of elements of $Z_n$

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory

So I was wondering how to find the order of elements under multiplication in $Z_n$. When $n$ is prime the problem is simpler since we know that then all the non-zero elements are units, and $|U(p)|=p-1$ so their order must divide $p-1$. This is some sort of clue, but when $n$ is not prime I have no idea how to tackle this problem and would appreciate the help.

Comment: Have you tried to apply the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: @NiekdeKleijn I did not cover that yet

Comment: Euler's theorem states that for $a$ coprime to $n$ we have $$a^{\varphi(n)}\equiv 1\mod n$$ hence the order must divide $\varphi(n)$. $\varphi(n)$ denotes the totient-function.

Comment: For small values of $n$, the way to tackle the problem is just to compute powers of your element until you get $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two generalizations of Fermat's theorem for composite modulus. They help reduce the number of possible candidates for multiplicative orders.

[Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem):

> $a^{\varphi (n)} \equiv 1 \bmod{n}$ when $\gcd(a,n)=1$

This is [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) for the group of units $U(n)$, which has order $\varphi (n)$.

Carmichael's theorem:

> $a^{\lambda (n)} \equiv 1 \bmod{n}$ when $\gcd(a,n)=1$

Here, [Carmichael's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) $\lambda (n)$ gives the exponent of $U(n)$. Naturally, $\lambda (n)$ divides $\varphi (n)$, but it is usually much smaller than $\varphi (n)$ when $n$ has several prime factors.